# Unscramble and Solve the Word Search

Tags: riddle, enigmatic-puzzle, word-search

Though the answer I'm looking for is a number and there is a little calculation involved. There are no hard sums here and each step is fairly simple (except maybe the last two)

> EtodKsteergytfifmilatertphoneqAladyaKauwsweenehW.================================================================etonwhopfiftyddhcumdidaohhn.=====================================================================================AXeH"theaegonenengas,nsyNyHgtaddnuopNYytrofxOzaaieherahBshnIme.,nrepeekpohssPSWvhWgveWo.eilessserdtOTsclown"=====MIesnneitgwrvocudehdiashsadnXr.==================================================================================aastNahkghlsioifntW,=============================================================================================TGTedlwMsuptSrY.=================================================================================================htggSgagklnuo.===================================================================================================rehtyvlMertuehixycSsnemursooonmesdnif,===========================================================================tdeeNgenmetimiinoaepcpmotqKdrXuuftrsmxgWnuvKwhyordvsgaoabteanmihhti.=============================================dsnootOooLrhfBehnrlntoiufAeghhenYimTzhrHdLcpoisijYuomrtgshueotusteiHhrlnandfandmrTKtyeehiaauookhnkapooa.=========sdnuopnshathhtttddrnpoeinaCbsesucxeRssUeoeseOibehnsJondkufieidehsinifHoluherDlariazlseHWhX?tPgTladyKkmrfSthLslhuo

Just un-jumble the letters, find some words, make sense of those words and work out what happened in the little story they tell.

Hint:

> Align, Remove, Re-align, Search, Re-arrange, Solve.

Extra Hint:

> There are 2 ways to "Re-align" only 1 will allow you to "Search" properly working out which is one of the (second) hardest parts of this puzzle.

Update (with hint):

> Len has extracted the correct word search arrangement. Beware there are quite a few decoy words the have crept in purely by chance. Pay attention to the punctuation which is stuck to the beginning and ends of words.

Comment: Can you make the text copyable?

Comment: @mmking Is that easier?

Comment: Yes, it is better now.

Comment: maybe just coincidence but I notice the following words in it without scrambling: phone, fifty, clown, lady

Comment: It's probably significant that the length of the string is 1243, which has factors 11 and 113.

Comment: Once we solve 1 step, will we realize that we've actually solved it? Or is the solution of first step another scrambled sequence?

Comment: Its hard to say without knowing what your result from the first step looks like. The first step has a more obvious clue than the second.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a partial answer.

**1. Align**

> As suggested by Emrakul, 1243 characters are arranged into 11 rows with 113 characters in each row.
>  [image: Align1]

**2. Remove**

> Remove all of the "=" characters

**3. Re-align**

> The remaining 589 characters can be arranged into 19 rows or 31 rows. I chose 19 rows of 31 characters because many more search words can be found in the next step.

**4. Search**

> Words can be found in all directions as shown. It seems unusual that there are multiple occurrences of words like daughter, fifty, and pound. The longest words are policeman and shopkeeper.
>  [image: Align2]

**5. Rearrange / 6. Solve**
If correct so far, perhaps somebody can figure out how the words need to be rearranged.

Comment: Well done Len. I really though someone would unscramble the grid a few minutes after I posted. The punctuation marks form important clues without which I doubt the next step could be solved,